# How to flashing bootloop Samsung Grand Prime SM-G530H with USB debugging Mode is disabled

Tags: boot-loop

i need your help..

my device bootloop.
Stuck in Odin mode.

Product Name: SM-G530H/DS

Current Binary : Samsung Official

System Status: Custom

here'e some information about the device and the tools:

1. debugging mode : disabled
2. root status : Unroot
3. Firmware : Official KitKat 4.4.4. G530HDCU1AOF1 (Indonesia)
4. Windows 7 SP1 32-bit
5. Samsung-USB-Driver-v1.5.63.0
6. Odin 3.04, Odin 3.07, Odin 3.1, Odin 3.2, And Odin 3.3 patched.
7. Root file for Sm-G530
8. Official firmware file SM-G530 all version and Indonesian version.
9. TWRP file for SM-G530

And then I try to :

1. wipe data/ cahe in recovery mode(Press power+volume up+home), the result is none...
2. root device via Odin, failed.
3. Install TWRP via Odin, failed
4. Flash via odin with some firmware ( HDC, HXX, HXC) the result also failed..

When i try to root or install TWRP or flashing with stock rom Odin displayed same error log:

=======================

File analysis..

SetupConnection..

Initialzation..

Get PIT for mapping..

Firmware update start..

SingleDownload.

aboot.mbn

sbl1.mbn

rpm.mbn

tz.mbn

hyp.mbn

NON-HLOS.bin

sec.dat

boot.img

FAIL! (Erase)

Complete(Write) operation failed.

All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)

=========

Now, after i repeate to Flashing with root file, flashing with stock rom official then i cant access to recovery mode (Press vol up+home+power) anymore, just stuck in Odin Mode like as i just switch on the device..always displayed "Firmware Upgrade ecountered an issue. Please select recovery mode in Kies & try again."

If the USB debugging mode is the problem for this case, so what can i do to fix it?

I found this and i trying, but im still fail to follow the instruction.

https://www.isrgrajan.com/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-in-android-using-recovery-mode.html

Anybody can help me to fix my case?

Here's some Error pictures..

[image]

![flash official rom all version]
Flashing Official firmware with 4 files All country
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrOkU.png)
[image: lash official rom all version]

Flashing Official firmware with single file Indonesian version
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2v6vC.png)
[image]

Installing TWRP
[image: installing twrp]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/usJSu.png)

Rooting
[image: rooting]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86240/discussion-on-question-by-jane-r-s-how-to-flashing-bootloop-samsung-grand-prime).